# how to convert opcodes to hexcodes

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

I am really stumped over here, please help...

I have ordered a bunch of books from intel, the software developers manuals, and inside of them they give me all these opcodes like "VEX.128..." or "0F 5B"

and these books say things like "this works with XMM registers" but none of the books talk about how to convert the word XMM into hexadecimal?

What I am trying to do is like write hello, world in pure hexadecimal without the use of an assembler! please help! I hope this made sense I am new to the world of assembly and hexcodes

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert assembler code to machine code by hand? If so, can you show the asm code you're trying to convert and where you're stuck?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am stuck at the very beginning, I dont know where to begin... I am trying to convert like the word "xmm" or "ymm" or any register for that matter into machine code!

Comment: Start by writing the asm code.

Comment: Intel does describe their operand encoding in the manual though

Comment: so this is for x86?  can we add the proper tag?

Comment: since there already exists an assembler its IMO good to use that tool with a disassembler or examine the output directly and compare it to what you are doing by hand or programmatically, with the open manual there as well to compare all three.

Comment: You don't have to "order" books, you can just download PDFs from Intel.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#three-volume.  There are several HTML versions of the per-instruction part of the volume 2 manual online, like http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADDPS.html, but it sounds like you need to read the intro parts of volume 2 that explain the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

The word XMM is not converted to hexadecimal. That an instruction uses XMM registers is a property of the opcode and prefixes. The index of the register operands are mostly encoded by the ModRM byte, a little in the prefix, for some operations on a GPR a register name is encoded in the opcode byte.

Complexities aside, here is a simple VEX-prefixed example, `vpaddb xmm1, xmm4, xmm6`. Its entry in the manual (under the `paddb` lemma) says to encode it as: `VEX.NDS.128.66.0F.WIG FC /r`

`VEX.NDS.128.66.0F.WIG` is for the VEX prefix. NDS means that the vvvv field encodes the source register. `128` means not to set the L bit, which makes the registers used the **X**MM versions, otherwise they would be the **Y**MM versions (so as you see this distinction is encoded by a single bit in the VEX prefix, not by writing the word "XMM" in hexadecimal exactly) `66` indicates a setting for the pp field that corresponds to a mandatory prefix in the legacy encoding, namely pp = 01. WIG = W-ignored, which doesn't really matter here.

Anyway it can be a 2-byte VEX prefix (no fancy opcode map, low register numbers), so start with `C5` and then combine the fields `~R|~vvvv|L|pp` (where `|` is concatenation). ~vvvv is the complement of vvvv, vvvv = 0100 (xmm**4**). The R field is an extension of the reg field of the ModRM byte, `xmm1` has an index lower than 8 so the R field is 0, hence ~R is 1. Combined, that second prefix byte is `1|1011|0|01 = D9`.

The opcode byte is `FC`, nothing funny happens here.

`/r` means to encode the rest of the operands as ModRM (+SIB), so here using mod=11 (two registers, no memory operand), rm = 110 (xmm**6**), reg = 001 (xmm**1**) so `11001110 = CE`

So in total `vpaddb xmm1,xmm4,xmm6` becomes `c5 d9 fc ce`.

You can find this information (and some details which I skipped) in Appendix B of the ISDM, "Instruction Formats and Encodings".